# bash: unset: неправильный идентификатор

Tags: linux, bash, path

```
$ unset QTDIR export PATH="$PWD/qtbase/bin:$PWD/qtrepotools/bin:$PATH"
bash: unset: `PATH=/home/alexandr/Qt/qt_git/5.8/src/qt5/qtbase/bin:/home/alexandr/Qt/qt_git/5.8/src/qt5/qtrepotools/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64:/home/alexandr/Android/Sdk/platform-tools:/home/alexandr/home/alexandr/Android/Sdk/tools:/home/alexandr/Qt/Tools/QtCreator/bin:/home/alexandr/Qt/5.6/android_armv7/bin:/home/alexandr/Qt/5.6/android_x86/bin:/home/alexandr/Qt/5.6/gcc_64/bin:/snap/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/db/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/bin': неправильный идентификатор
```

В чём заключается ошибка и как её исправить?

Comment: unset QTDIR; export PATH ... точку с запятой забыли

Comment: @0xdb готов принять за ответ. Брал отсюда http://wiki.qt.io/Building_Qt_5_from_Git/ru

Comment: А когда вы мне галочку поставите? А то мне фантиков не подсыпят,  и перед пацанами не порисуешься даже.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

По видимому при генерации веб-сайтов происходят иногда ошибки. 
Автор взял с [чаво](http://wiki.qt.io/Building_Qt_5_from_Git/ru):

```
unset QTDIR export PATH="$PWD/qtbase/bin:$PWD/qtrepotools/bin:$PATH"
```

где не хватает `;`. На конце строки оно не обязательно, а в одну строку предыдущая команда получит следующую как аргумент.

В оригинале (там же на En) этой строчки я не нашёл. Вот [здесь](http://wiki.wildsong.biz/index.php?title=QT5) по-видимому правильно.